# Call Javascript function on <a> element onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, anchor, jquery-events

I need to call a Javascript function on `<a>` element `click` event. When the page will initially load it will display the temperature in `°C`. Later on user can click on temperature to change it from `°C to °F` and vice versa without page refresh.

Code :

HTML:

```
<html>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/51b73c8fb8.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="tempOutCont">
      <div class="tempInCont">
        <span id="headDetails"></span>
        <div id="iconTemp">
          <img id="icon"></img>
          <a id="unitLink" href="https://www.google.com"></a>
        </div>
        <span id="mainWeather"></span>
        <span id="detailsHead">Details</span>
        <div id="listDetails">
          <ul>
            <li>Wind<span id="windText" class="listDetailsItem"></span></li>
            <li>Pressure<span id="pressureText" class="listDetailsItem"></span></li>
            <li>Humidity<span id="humidText" class="listDetailsItem"></span></li>
            <li>Cloudiness<span id="cloudText" class="listDetailsItem"></span></li>
          </ul>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mainContainer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.tempOutCont {
  background-color: white;
  height: 20em;
  width: 40em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.tempInCont {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#headDetails {
  border: 0.1em white solid;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#iconTemp {
  border: 0.1em white solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#mainWeather {
  text-align: center;
}
#detailsHead {
  text-align: center;
}
#listDetails {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  margin-left: 10em;
  text-align: left;
}
.listDetailsItem {
  margin-left: 5em;
  text-align: left;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
/*<iframe src="https://codepen.io/shaan046/full/jaggro/" allow="geolocation"></iframe>*/
var appId = "675645ead57721be136750f9cfc0acca";
var unit;
var temperature;

var changeUnit = function changeUnit(unit, temperature) {
  console.log(unit);
  if (unit === "C") {
    temperature = temperature * 1.8 + 32;
    unit = "F";
    document.getElementById("unitLink").innerHTML = temperature + "°F";
  } else if (unit === "F") {
    temperature = (temperature - 32) / 1.8;
    unit = "C";
    document.getElementById("unitLink").innerHTML = temperature + "°C";
  } else if (unit === "K") {
    temperature = temperature - 273.15;
    unit = "C";
    document.getElementById("unitLink").innerHTML = temperature + "°C";
  }
  return false;
};

var getWeatherData = function getWeatherData() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showPosition(position) {
      var lat = String(position.coords.latitude);
      var lon = String(position.coords.longitude);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:
          "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
          lat +
          "&lon=" +
          lon +
          "&appid=" +
          appId,
        success: function(json) {
          document.getElementById("headDetails").innerHTML =
            "Weather in " + json.name + "," + json.sys.country;
          document.getElementById("icon").src =
            "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + json.weather[0].icon + ".png";
          changeUnit("K", json.main.temp);
          document.getElementById("mainWeather").innerHTML =
            json.weather[0].main;
          document.getElementById("windText").innerHTML =
            json.wind.speed + "m/s";
          document.getElementById("pressureText").innerHTML =
            json.main.pressure + "hpa";
          document.getElementById("humidText").innerHTML =
            json.main.humidity + "%";
          document.getElementById("cloudText").innerHTML =
            json.clouds.all + "%";
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  getWeatherData();
  $("#unitLink").onclick = changeUnit(unit, temperature);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: When i click on the text 17°C which is a anchor text i set using function call, nothing happens. The function call sets the text correctly by converting temperature from Kelvin(K) to Celcius(C). But after that nothing happens on <a> click.

Comment: This line `$("#unitLink").onclick = changeUnit(unit, temperature);` doesn't do what you think it does. It just adds a custom property to a jQuery object.

Comment: So what i want to to do here is call a function on click event. May be you can suggest a better way to do that. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at the basics here. `$("#unitLink")` returns a __jQuery object__, then you're adding `onclick` property to that object, which eventually evaluates to `false` since `changeUnit` returns `false`. Or fails alltogether, if `unit` and/or `temperature` are not defined at the DOM ready.

Comment: Read up on [how the jQuery click handler works](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery

```
$('#elementToChangeID').text("something");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem here is that the function has arguments passed into it. How can i pass value from JS to HTML in that case ? Won't be possible i guess.

Comment: Don't bind obtrusively into HTML. This is a bad practice.

Comment: Are you trying to edit HTML elements with values set by your JS?

Comment: Yes.. I need to do that

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to bind events to DOM is:

```
<a href="#" id="someLink">link</a>
```

with JS:

```
$('#someLink').click(function(){
// do something
});
```

Not using the `onclick` in HTML.

The advantages are

- behaviour (Javascript) is separated from presentation (HTML)
- no mixing of languages
- you're using a Javascript framework like jQuery that can handle most cross-browser issues for you
- You can add behaviour to a lot of HTML elements at once without code duplication

Comment: I tried -   $("#unitLink").click(changeUnit(unit, temperature));   Am i doing it right way ? As nothing happens on clicking.